# How to display an image uploaded to Azure Blob Storage in the browser

Tags: image, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading images via a POST request to an azure function and the azure function is meant to store the image in the blob storage. It seems to upload the image but when trying to access it in the browser using the url the image data has a string of metadata being attached to it.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0NovMaDHJqbbnTvc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="client-logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png

ï¿½PNG


IHDRï¿½x>Z  pHYsï¿½ï¿½
MiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexÚSwXï¿½ï¿½>ï¿½ï¿½eVBï¿½ï¿½lï¿½"#ï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½ï¿½aï¿½@Åï¿½
Vï¿½HUÄï¿½ {...Symbols like these...}
ï¿½ï¿½~Vï¿½yï¿½sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ï¿ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½rï«©ï¿½:ï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½y=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ç½ï¿½(ï¿½@ï¿½Pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cÇ§ï¿½Oï¿½>ï¿½|ï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½%Ò3<ï¿½iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
        {... Metadata ...}
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

Not even sure what format that is or if it's the correct one for the image to be stored in order to be able to use the url to eventually display it in the browser/

Thanks

P.S. The code used to upload it as per @AMOR - MSFT comment is

```
if (context.req.method === 'POST') {
     blobService.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, blob, context.req.rawBody, {contentSettings: {contentType: 'image/png'}}, function(){
        context.done();
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you handle file post in Azure Function, Could you provide your key code?

Comment: @Amor-MSFT the main bit for uploading it is in the update

Comment: As the function name says (`createBlockBlobFromText`) its for uploading texts, you may want to use `createBlockBlobFromFile` or `createBlockBlobFromStream`